# Firebase Query snapshot nil?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a simple chat app to learn Swift and Firebase. I have a query that checks for a chat room's messages to load into a tableView. The query returns a snapshot but I'm having trouble getting the data to store and load it properly. I created a dictionary from the snapshot so I can get the individual child values but they are returning nil:

```
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { snapshot in

            print(snapshot)

            let indexPaths = self.messages.enumerated().map {
                IndexPath(row: $0.0, section: 0)
            }

            guard let messagesDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] else { return }
            guard let sender = messagesDict["sender"] as? String else { return }
            guard let text = messagesDict["text"] as? String else { return }
            guard let timestamp = messagesDict["timestamp"] as? Int else { return }

            let message = Message.init(key: snapshot.key, sender: sender as! String, text: text as! String, timestamp: timestamp)

            self.messages.append(message)

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
```

`po messagesDict` returns data at the breakpoint:

```
▿ 1 element
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : "-KotqLUUucaRagTRt967"
    ▿ value : 3 elements
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : sender
        - value : eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3
      ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - key : text
        - value : test
      ▿ 2 : 2 elements
        - key : timestamp
        - value : 1499914135546
```

The app gets to the next breakpoint where I set `guard let sender` but the app hits return and stops executing the rest of the block of code. How do I properly access sender, text, and timestamp elements so I can set them to variables and store them in the array for my table?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on this for a while and I could use another pair of eyes!

Thanks!!

***Additional info:***

**Query:**

`let query = rootRef.child("chat-messages/\(chatKey)")`

**Database structure:**

```
{
  "chat-messages" : {
    "-KotqKI4zF9cS5XMR9WU" : {
      "-KotqLUUucaRagTRt967" : {
        "sender" : "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3",
        "text" : "test",
        "timestamp" : 1499914135546
      }
    },
    "-KotqvBoFFzOTY6Q1fO7" : {
      "-KotqwGAJ85NuAp-Lh3Z" : {
        "sender" : "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3",
        "text" : "test",
        "timestamp" : 1499914290279
      }
    },
    "-KotsNgF0ou5MIDn2l5K" : {
      "-KotsOSXw7OS_3xuXZgP" : {
        "sender" : "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3",
        "text" : "test",
        "timestamp" : 1499914671997
      },
      "-KotsPqrCpipMLulNNFl" : {
        "sender" : "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3",
        "text" : "test44",
        "timestamp" : 1499914677715
      }
    },
    "-Kotsv1Vv19dEF2q7XQu" : {
      "-KotsvYO9JvLY8gdTnA0" : {
        "sender" : "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3",
        "text" : "test",
        "timestamp" : 1499914811675
      },
      "-KotsvxKXzIwbyvbwLPp" : {
        "sender" : "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3",
        "text" : "test",
        "timestamp" : 1499914813335
      },
      "-Kotsw9vLiEf6KquU__e" : {
        "sender" : "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3",
        "text" : "test",
        "timestamp" : 1499914814205
      },
      "-KotswHnzmfkEXih1O7y" : {
        "sender" : "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3",
        "text" : "test",
        "timestamp" : 1499914814709
      },
      "-KotszHKBt254jZnUMAl" : {
        "sender" : "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3",
        "text" : "test46456",
        "timestamp" : 1499914826967
      }
    },
    "-KoyheS01YxWExSNxl_H" : {
      "-Koyhf3G-FPEDrxQOcpU" : {
        "sender" : "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3",
        "text" : "test",
        "timestamp" : 1499995746607
      }
    },
    "-Koyjc_aBaF1kFE-8Bll" : {
      "-Koyjd9PnO6sPOhS7P27" : {
        "sender" : "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3",
        "text" : "test",
        "timestamp" : 1499996263096
      },
      "-KoyjdzSEi5twTVQMGOu" : {
        "sender" : "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3",
        "text" : "test",
        "timestamp" : 1499996266491
      },
      "-Koyje2C9E524kV7nhLY" : {
        "sender" : "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3",
        "text" : "test",
        "timestamp" : 1499996266730
      }
    },
    "-KpfUGw45F1FU2IrR87A" : {
      "sender" : "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3",
      "text" : "test",
      "timestamp" : 1500746948396
    },
    "-KpfUHQGuTDi4yZutS5K" : {
      "sender" : "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3",
      "text" : "test",
      "timestamp" : 1500746950368
    },
    "-KpfUHdSXeTzauATsDAP" : {
      "sender" : "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3",
      "text" : "test",
      "timestamp" : 1500746951277
    },
    "-Kpfia0fXsoqpRtIr1kU" : {
      "sender" : "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3",
      "text" : "gerg",
      "timestamp" : 1500750962815
    }
  },
  "chat-participants" : {
    "-KotqKI4zF9cS5XMR9WU" : {
      "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3" : {
        "username" : "tester"
      }
    },
    "-KotqvBoFFzOTY6Q1fO7" : {
      "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3" : {
        "username" : "tester"
      }
    },
    "-KotsNgF0ou5MIDn2l5K" : {
      "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3" : {
        "username" : "tester"
      }
    },
    "-Kotsv1Vv19dEF2q7XQu" : {
      "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3" : {
        "username" : "tester"
      }
    },
    "-KoyheS01YxWExSNxl_H" : {
      "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3" : {
        "username" : "tester"
      }
    },
    "-Koyjc_aBaF1kFE-8Bll" : {
      "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3" : {
        "username" : "tester"
      }
    },
    "-KpfLBjQdPiX2kSrl1yF" : {
      "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3" : {
        "username" : "tester"
      }
    }
  },
  "chats" : {
    "-KotqKI4zF9cS5XMR9WU" : {
      "currentName" : "test",
      "date" : 1499914130657
    },
    "-KotqvBoFFzOTY6Q1fO7" : {
      "currentName" : "test",
      "date" : 1499914285904
    },
    "-KotsNgF0ou5MIDn2l5K" : {
      "currentName" : "test",
      "date" : 1499914668844
    },
    "-Kotsv1Vv19dEF2q7XQu" : {
      "currentName" : "test",
      "date" : 1499914809570
    },
    "-KoyheS01YxWExSNxl_H" : {
      "currentName" : "test",
      "date" : 1499995744095
    },
    "-Koyjc_aBaF1kFE-8Bll" : {
      "currentName" : "test",
      "date" : 1499996260740
    },
    "-KpfLBjQdPiX2kSrl1yF" : {
      "currentName" : "test3222",
      "date" : 1500744567786
    }
  },
  "user-chats" : {
    "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3" : {
      "-KotqKI4zF9cS5XMR9WU" : {
        "chatKey" : "-KotqKI4zF9cS5XMR9WU",
        "currentName" : "test"
      },
      "-KotqvBoFFzOTY6Q1fO7" : {
        "chatKey" : "-KotqvBoFFzOTY6Q1fO7",
        "currentName" : "test"
      },
      "-KotsNgF0ou5MIDn2l5K" : {
        "chatKey" : "-KotsNgF0ou5MIDn2l5K",
        "currentName" : "test"
      },
      "-Kotsv1Vv19dEF2q7XQu" : {
        "chatKey" : "-Kotsv1Vv19dEF2q7XQu",
        "currentName" : "test"
      },
      "-KoyheS01YxWExSNxl_H" : {
        "chatKey" : "-KoyheS01YxWExSNxl_H",
        "currentName" : "test"
      },
      "-Koyjc_aBaF1kFE-8Bll" : {
        "chatKey" : "-Koyjc_aBaF1kFE-8Bll",
        "currentName" : "test"
      },
      "-KpfLBjQdPiX2kSrl1yF" : {
        "chatKey" : "-KpfLBjQdPiX2kSrl1yF",
        "currentName" : "test3222"
      }
    }
  },
  "user-friends" : {
    "36HDn5XyxjMCcMluJJ9KPBOCDMm1" : {
      "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3" : {
        "username" : "tester"
      }
    },
    "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3" : {
      "36HDn5XyxjMCcMluJJ9KPBOCDMm1" : {
        "username" : "tester2"
      }
    }
  },
  "user-invites" : {
    "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3" : {
      "36HDn5XyxjMCcMluJJ9KPBOCDMm1" : {
        "username" : "tester2"
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "36HDn5XyxjMCcMluJJ9KPBOCDMm1" : {
      "email" : "tester2@test.com",
      "username" : "tester2"
    },
    "eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3" : {
      "email" : "test@test.com",
      "username" : "tester"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your query ? And your database structure ?

Comment: Thanks for your help on this! I edited the question to include the query and the database structure.

Comment: @freeman I added a suggested solution a couple of days ago - solve the issue or still having problems?

Answer (score 6):

Your dictionary look like :

```
▿ 1 element
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : "-KotqLUUucaRagTRt967"
    ▿ value : 3 elements
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : sender
        - value : eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3
      ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - key : text
        - value : test
      ▿ 2 : 2 elements
        - key : timestamp
        - value : 1499914135546
```

But in fact it should look like (If you want to access to dictionary["sender"]) :

```
▿ 2 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : sender
    - value : eGTYRSo81JefgasYLRHUFHUTnEC3
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    - key : text
    - value : test
  ▿ 2 : 2 elements
    - key : timestamp
    - value : 1499914135546
```

**First solution :**

You need to add .child("-KotqLUUucaRagTRt967") in your query.

**OR**

**Second solution :**

You need to do something like that :

```
query.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        guard let value = child.value as? NSDictionary else {
            return
        }

        guard let sender = value["sender"] as? String else {
            return
        }

        // You can user the sender
    }
})
```

**UPDATE :**

```
query.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        if let value = child.value as? [String:Any], let sender = value["sender"] as? String {  
            // You can user the sender
        }
    }
})
```

**NOTE**

I replaced **observeSingleEvent** with **observe**, as **Frank van Puffelen** said, it's an uncommon combination for **.childAdded**.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting error `Value of type Any has no member value`. It errors on `value = child.value`. Any ideas?

Comment: @freeman did you make sure to include the `guard let` before the `value = child.value`?

Comment: @RajatKhare yes it still errors on this line `guard let value = child.value as? NSDictionary else {return}`. XCode suggests changing it to `guard let value = (child as AnyObject).value as? NSDictionary else {return}` but then that throws error `Ambiguous use of value`

Answer (score 5):

I do not think you want a ChildAdded handler, so I go with a observeSingleEvent example since you want to query data from the database at that time without triggers. When you use a observeSingleEvent, it is important to keep the database in sync. I would recommend using the code below:

```
query.keepSynched(true) //keeps data in sync with database, if you have data persistince on in your appDelegate
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in //notice the changed here
            print(snapshot)
            //Since you want to loop again because there could be multiple
            //messages in that chatroom which all have a unique ID, do this loop:
            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
               //this is 1 single message here
               let values = rest.value as? NSDictionary
               for (key, value) in values{
               print("Key: \(key), value: \(value)") 
               }
               //lets say you want to check if there is a value with a key named "text":
            let textUser = values?["text"] as? String ?? "No text found" 
               //providing a default value if there is no text. You could leave it empty, than it is nil (not recommend)
               //Not only is this a lot more readable, I do not use force unwrapping so your app 
               //cannot cause an exception.

               //Get more values from the dictionary as I did with textUser
               //Initialize message than here. You will see you do not need to force unwrap anything :D
               }

            }

        })
```

Comment: "You and Pipiks combine a observeSingleEvent with a ChildAdded, this two do not go together" While it's an uncommon combination, there is no technical reason these can't be combined.

Comment: Agreed, don't see why you couldn't combine a single event and childAdded?

Comment: @Yasir I did not know for sure, thats why the "I think??!". From the docs I read that childAdded is triggered each time a new child is added. An observeSingleEvent will read the data as it is at that time. I thought that two would not work together, but Frank has already corrected me, I will edit that part out.

Answer (score 4):

As **Pipiks** explained, your issue is that you are attempting to access individual message details at one level higher than the returned data.

The snapshot value is giving you a dictionary of chat messages, where the top level's keys are the chat message keys. To map your returned data to an array of messages, I would use the following code:

```
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { snapshot in

    guard let messagesDict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }

    self.messages = messagesDict.flatMap({ (messageId: String, messageData: Any) -> Message? in
        guard
            let sender = messageData["sender"] as? String,
            let text = messageData["text"] as? String,
            let timestamp = messageData["timestamp"] as? Int,
            let message = Message(key: messageKey, sender: sender, text: text, timestamp: timestamp) else {
                return nil
        }
        return message
    })

    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

What this does is map your dictionary of messages to an array of `Message` objects.

I have used a flatMap to filter out any messages which do not have sender, text or timestamp values (so the flatMap returns a `[Message]` object).

Does that solve the issue?

Comment: I left out the indexPaths code, as it doesn't look like it is used anywhere :)