# Get child nodes from firebase (Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

How can i get child nodes from firebase?
Firebase struct is here:

[image: firebase struct]

Me need to get a child "Photos" for each child above. And later add to collectionView each child "Photo".

My firebase struct:

```
{

"Студии" : {
 "Бабулька" : {
  "Photo" : {
    "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185"
  },
  "address" : "Сатурн",
  "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
  "image1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
  "name" : "Карапулька"
},
 "Дубаи" : {
  "Photo" : {
    "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city1.jpg?alt=media&token=c442fd8f-4cc4-4e30-8242-975aaf5427dc"
  },
  "address" : "Тутушка",
  "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city1.jpg?alt=media&token=c442fd8f-4cc4-4e30-8242-975aaf5427dc",
  "name" : "Дубаи"
},
 "Лондон" : {
  "Photo" : {
    "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/oko1.jpg?alt=media&token=fedea2cb-93b1-496c-9392-0b95f4ada7b5"
  },
  "address" : "Бейкер стрит",
  "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/oko1.jpg?alt=media&token=fedea2cb-93b1-496c-9392-0b95f4ada7b5",
  "name" : "Лондон"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45369544/7715250

Comment: Please post your Firebase structures as text, no images. That way if we need to use the structure in the answer, we don't have to retype it. You can get your Firebase structure as text from the Firebase console->Three dots->export JSON

Comment: Thanks for help. I added firebase struct in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get to the data you want, iterate over all of the child notes of the main parent node. Assume the following structure

```
posts
   post_0
     Photo
       image: "https://www....."
   post_1
     Photo
       image: "https://www....."
```

and the code to get the image urls...

```
let ref = self.ref.child("posts")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let imageSnap = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "Photo")
        let dict = imageSnap.value as! [String: Any]
        let url = dict["image"] as! String
        print(url)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it works ;) Maybe you can prompt how load an array of images? for example if in each "Photos" I will have "image1", "image2", "image3" or more or less.

Comment: Don't store data in Firebase Array's as Firebase Arrays Are Evil see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179477/firebase-changing-layout-of-child-data-information-in-android/43191862#43191862). They could be stored as key: value pairs with the keys being generated by childByAutoId. so it would be  images/firebase_key_0: image0 and /images/firebase_key_1: image1 etc.