# Firebase snapshot returns null

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi guys I have been using firebase to write and read values from the database. It was working awesome until I wrote a function to retrieve values or products stored using swift in the following way.

Here is my code

```
func retrieveLiveUrlFor(product: Product){
    if let path = product.prodRef{
        print("Looking for : \(path)")
        var liveUrl = ""
        let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: path)
        ref.observe(. value, with: {
            snapshot in
            print("Snap : \(snapshot.value)")
            if snapshot.exists(){
                print("Snap : \(snapshot.value)")
                let dic = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                if dic != nil{
                    let url = dic?["liveUrl"] as? String
                    print("Url is here")
                    if url != nil{
                        print("URL is not nil")
                        liveUrl = url as! String
                    }
                }
            }

            if (self.productdelegate != nil){
                print("Calling Product delegate")
                self.productdelegate?.liveUrlObtained!(liveUrl: liveUrl)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

And this is the value of the path that I am trying to retrieve

> Products/Live/Global/WpMvDJZUclRlfHFJsSlBEbi0jHf1

And here is the snap of the firebase database

[image]

The snapshot.value alwasy returns null in swift.
When I print using

```
print("Snap: \(snapshot.value)")
```

It prints the following

> Snap : Optional()
>   Please guide me what I am doing wrong so that I can get to it.

Comment: Check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45369544/7715250

Comment: I think your database structure is not good check firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data avoid nesting data structure its can be create problem when you have and get thousands of records while qurey

Comment: @AnasMehar Can you please explain what's wrong in it? And if there is some discrepancy then you must provide a solution than to just say its wrong. Please, i am waiting for the answer.

Comment: i am not say that's method wrong..only say not good according to firebase docs.When u deep query in your above type of structure the firebase work slow that's way to avoid nesting nodes.

Comment: @AnasMehar So what should i do here? Please do suggest something as per my scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are observing using the .value event, then a return of snapshot.value as nil means that the snapshot value does not exist at that reference. Try printing the snapshot as a whole and the snapshot.key

ideally the reference you need is

```
  let ref = Database.database.reference().child("Products").child("Live").child("Global").child("WpMvDJZUclRlfHFJsSlBEbi0jHf1")
```

The observer would function like this:

```
ref.observe(.value) {(snapshot) in
print(snapshot.value!)
}
```

Comment: "means that the snapshot value does not exist at that reference" and later on you force unwrap the snapshot

Comment: Actually i can not use separate children as i get a path to a particular product.

Comment: Snap : Snap (WpMvDJZUclRlfHFJsSlBEbi0jHf1) <null>

Comment: This is what it printed when i called print(snapshot)

Comment: @J.Doe you are correct there is no need for the force unwrap, my mistake. However if the snapshot contains no value, a print(snapshot.value!) will print <null>

Comment: it does contain a value as seen in the picture

Comment: @SalmanAli If there are no other values apart from the key kr7giFRpNauqYs7FCqg at node WpMvDJZUclRlfHFJsSlBEbi0jHf1, you would have to use the key kr7giFRpNauqYs7FCqg to get your value.

Comment: Nah, all the other data should appear in the data snapshot, this is weird.

Comment: @SalmanAli a work around could be to use .childAdded as the event and use and if statement and a childkey to determine which child to store in the dictionary