# Swift Firebase read children of a child

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

So I am trying to read the children of the autoID children beneath "Recipes" below is a picture of my Firebase database and beneath that is the method that is supposed to retrieve the value of "Description" and "Name" and insert them into variables.

The error that I am currently getting when running the app is this:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x10ad2afb8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10ad2bfa8).
```

[image: My Firebase database]

```
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    databaseHandle = ref?.child("Recipes").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        for snap in snapshot.children
        {
            let recipeSnap = snap as! DataSnapshot
            let recipeID = recipeSnap.key
            let dict = recipeSnap.value as! [String:AnyObject]
            let recipeName = dict["Name"] as! String
            let recipeDescription = dict["Description"] as! String
            print("key = \(recipeID) and name = \(recipeName) and description = \(recipeDescription)")
        }
  }
```

The print statement is just there for testing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45369544/7715250 maybe this will help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following and let me know if it works now:

```
// SEARCHES FOR SHARING CODE IN DATABASE (ONLINE)
let parentRef = Database.database().reference().child("Recipes")

parentRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

    // SHOWING WHATEVER WAS RECEIVED FROM THE SERVER JUST AS A CONFIRMATION. FEEL FREE TO DELETE THIS LINE.
    print(snapshot)

    // PROCESSES VALUES RECEIVED FROM SERVER
    if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {

       // DATA WAS NOT FOUND
       print("– – – Data was not found – – –")

    } else {

        // DATA WAS FOUND
        for user_child in (snapshot.children) {

            let user_snap = user_child as! DataSnapshot
            let dict = user_snap.value as! [String: String?]

            // DEFINE VARIABLES FOR LABELS
            let recipeName = dict["Name"] as? String
            let recipeDescription = dict["Description"] as? String
            print("– – – Data for the recipe \(recipeName) with the description \(recipeDescription) was found successfully! – – –")
        }
    }
}
```

If you only want to retrieve the name and description for one *specific* recipe, you should change the third line to

```
parentRef.queryEqual(toValue:DefineWhatToSearchForHere).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
```

If you constantly want to update to reflect changes, you can either call this function every x seconds using a timer and adding it to `override func viewDidLoad()` such as

```
time = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateFBData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

after creating a function called `func updateFBData()` in which you do whatever you want to do to get new data (see above) and calling it in a defined `timeInterval`

or you can do what Attila Hegedüs [in this excellent tutorial.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer, it kind of worked except that I wanted to store the actual values in recipeName and recipeDescription, not the dictionary, can you help me fix that and edit the answer? Also why did you change it to a observeSingleEvent? What does that mean? Will it not listen constantly and update the app whenever I insert something in the database?

Comment: I just edited your answer, this worked for me, it displays exactly what I want it to, the actual name and description, did I do it right or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @random1234 Nice, glad that it's working now for you – you're right, the `as? String` provides the output in the format you want, I simply forgot adding it. :)

Comment: Awesome =) just one problem left however, I want it to constantly observe, not observeSingleEvent, I want my tableView of recipes to update whenever I add or delete a recipe.

Comment: Can't I just simply change it to "observe" instead and it will update in realtime? When I change it now it adds all the firebase items to the tableView again, even if they still exist. Isn't there something I can change so it only adds the item I just added and not the old ones

Comment: Hey I have a problem, whenever I show another view and then go back to the main one it reloads all the cells in the tableview so I get duplicates of everything, is there no way that I can change my "observeSingleEvent" to a "observe" with ".childAdded"? This will also make it update automatically.