# Cannot set value of Textfield as Firebase search result - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a search function in my app to search my firebase db based on a pub name entered. This is working correctly & returning the correct record in my console. However I'm trying to display the relating info to that search query as values on my textfields.

```
var drinkReference: DatabaseReference!
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

@IBOutlet weak var pintImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pubName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pubLocation: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var price: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var rating: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var comment: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var searchText: UITextField!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AddDrinkVC .dismissKeyboard))

    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    drinkReference = Database.database().reference().child("Drinks");

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SearchVC.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SearchVC.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}




@IBAction func searchIsClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    searchT()
}



@IBAction func homeClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    homeClicked()
}


func searchT() {
    // You must cast pub variable as String.
    guard let pub: String = searchText.text else { return }



    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("Drinks")

    let query = databaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "pub").queryStarting(atValue: pub).queryEnding(atValue: "\(String(describing: pub))\\uf8ff")

    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard snapshot.exists() != false else {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "This pub hasn't been visited yet. We'll get there.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let search = UIAlertAction(title: "Want to add the drink yourself?", style: .default) { [weak self] _ in
                self?.uploadClicked()
            }
            alert.addAction(search)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close & Search again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


            return }
        print(snapshot.value as Any)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else {
                print(snapshot)
                return
            }



            let returnedPubName = dict["pub"] as? String
            let returnedPubLocation = dict["location"] as? String
            let returnedPintPrice = dict["price"] as? String
            let returnedPintRating = dict["rating"] as? String
            let returnedComment = dict["comment"] as? String



            self.pubName.text?.append(returnedPubName!)
            self.pubLocation.text?.append(returnedPubLocation!)
            self.price.text?.append(returnedPintPrice!)
            self.rating.text?.append(returnedPintRating!)
            self.comment.text?.append(returnedComment!)

        }
    }
}
```

When I try to assign the value of 'pubName' to the textfield of the same name it's receiving nil. Is this due to my 'guard let dict....' code?

Does anyone know how & where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks, E
[image]

Comment: why you are using append and is your textfields are inside tableView

Comment: @wings No they're not in a table view. I've used append for updating textfields before & it's worked? The issue here is the code 'let pubName = dict["pub"] as? String" is setting pubName as nil, and I can't figure out what's causing it

Comment: let pubName = dict["pub"] as? String are you getting the value or getting null ?

Comment: why are you using the same variable to get a value from your dictionary and for your textfield? This looks weird `self.pubName.text?.append(pubName!)`

Comment: @wings I'm getting null for it. I can see on my xcode console that the search is returning the correct values but am having trouble assigning those values to variables so as I can use those variables

Comment: @schtipoun Because that's just the name I've used. Can change the name of the local variables all I like, they're still being set to null because of the issue I'm having

Comment: @EoghanCasey alright, and if you make directly `self.pubName.text?.append(dict["pub"] as! String)`, the textfield will update as soon as the value as been retrieved from the snapshot, no?

Comment: can you show the whole code what exactly you are doing you don't need to append textfield in this situation i think

Comment: @Schtipoun I tried that & got the same error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: use self.pubName.text? = returnedPubName ?? ""

Comment: @wings I've added all of the code in there for you now! I don't think append or not is the issue, the issue is that I'm receiving null for the variables after the dict[..] code

Comment: okay wait let me give the solution

Comment: I think your guard let takes time and so it's not retrieved when you want to append the data. I understand the value of guard let but did you try with an if let just to check if, this time, you have data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So through trial and error & with the help of a few folk this is the working code, as a note I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way or anything, but it works so c'est la vie.

```
func searchT() {
    // You must cast pub variable as String.
        guard let pub: String = searchText.text else { return }

        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("Drinks")

        let query = databaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "pub").queryStarting(atValue: pub).queryEnding(atValue: "\(String(describing: pub))\\uf8ff")

        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            guard snapshot.exists() != false else {

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "This pub hasn't been visited yet. We'll get there.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                let search = UIAlertAction(title: "Want to add the drink yourself?", style: .default) { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.uploadClicked()
                }
                alert.addAction(search)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close & Search again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                return }
            print(snapshot.value as Any)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {


                // DATA WAS FOUND
                for user_child in (snapshot.children) {

                    let user_snap = user_child as! DataSnapshot
                    let dict = user_snap.value as! [String: String?]

                    // DEFINE VARIABLES FOR LABELS
                    let returnedPubName = dict["pub"] as? String
                    let returnedPubLocation = dict["location"] as? String
                    let returnedPintPrice = dict["price"] as? String
                    let returnedPintRating = dict["rating"] as? String
                    let returnedComment = dict["comment"] as? String



                    self.pubName.text?.append(returnedPubName!)
                    self.pubLocation.text?.append(returnedPubLocation!)
                    self.price.text?.append(returnedPintPrice!)
                    self.rating.text?.append(returnedPintRating!)
                    self.comment.text?.append(returnedComment!)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pay particular attention to the code following the comment //DATA WAS FOUND, that's accessing the values of the children data records.

Answer (score 1):

Create a struct like this:-

```
struct Names {

var pub: String = ""
var location: String = ""
var price: String = ""
var rating: String = ""
var comment: String = ""


init(data: [String:Any]) {

    if let obj = data["pub"] as? String {
        self.pub = obj
    }
    if let obj = data["location"] as? String {
        self.location = obj
    }
    if let obj = data["price"] as? String {
        self.price = obj
    }
    if let obj = data["rating"] as? String {
        self.rating = obj
    }
    if let obj = data["comment"] as? String {
        self.comment = obj
    }
}
}
```

And in your controller class create a variable

```
var names: [Names] = [Names]()
```

Then in your `searchT` method do this

```
guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else {

            return
        }
        self.names.append(Names(data: dict))
            print(self.names)
```

And then use

```
 self.pubName.text = names.first?.pub
```

And if it not works just try after

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {

        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else {

            return
        }
        self.names.append(Names(data: dict))
            print(self.names)


    }
     self.pubName.text = names.first?.pub
```

Comment: Hi - thank you for this. I am getting an error on your 'guard let dict....' method. The error : "Variable declared in 'guard' condition is not usable in its body" is being thrown on the line "self.names.append(Names(data: dict))"

Is this error not occurring for you?

Comment: Getting there, there's a single record in the Names list, but the values in that list aren't being set. So I can see in my console "[ProjectName.SearchVC.Names(pub: "", location: "", price: "", rating: "", comment: "")]" is that due to not setting the variables correctly?

Comment: can you show your database values any screenshot of your database

Comment: Updated the question above. I can see that the values of the variables isn't being updated. so the "var pub: String = "" " isn't being changed at all

Comment: bro try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46487024/swift-firebase-read-children-of-a-child I think your code is not fetching the data from firebase and this too https://www.raywenderlich.com/3-firebase-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: you beautiful divil you, bit of a mix up between your help & the help there got me to it. Delighted!